# bash - extract filenames from html file containing multiple links

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, html

I have downloaded an html file autogenerated by a script on a webpage.
The file contains multiple links, including links to images
I am trying to extract the full names of the images, for example

```
<a href="000000.jpg" title="image name.jpg" target="_blank">Image name.jpg</a>
```

from the above I want to get `"Image name.jpg"` stored in a file. Since there are hundreds of these, I parse the file and store each name as it comes up with the following command:

```
grep -i -E -o "target=\"_blank\">([[:graph:]]*)\.(jpg|png|gif|webm)" "$thread" | cut -f 2 -d '>' | sed 's/ /_/g' - > "$names"
```

where "`$thread`" is the name of the html file, "`$names`" is the list of filenames as output.  I use "`cut`" to remove the `'target="_blank">'` portion, then convert the spaces to underscores.

Since there are several other links in the file, I specify the extensions to grab (images and webm).  everything else should be ignored.  I got it to the point where it is grabbing these links only, but then it misses some.

Some files contain spaces and non-alphanumeric characters.  If I use `[[:print:]]` which should cover all these cases i get nothing, or I get a bit of the `<head>` portion of html and nothing else.  If I use `[[:graph:][:space:]]`, I also get nothing.  If I just use `[[:graph:]]` (as above) or `[[:alnum:][:punct:]]` I can get files with alphanumeric/other characters (like "`filenamewith(parenthesis).jpg`"), but not spaces, and the reverse is also true, `[[:alnum:][:space:]]` works but omits the other printable characters ("`file name with spaces.jpg`" works but not "with(parenthesis,comma or other.jpg").

Supposedly `[[:print:]]` covers all cases but I don't get what I need, which if I'm understanding correctly,

`grep -E -o` should only match (per the case above) :
`*.jpg *.png *.gif` or `*.webm`

I have tried `grep` with and without `-E/-o/-e` in different variations.

Any ideas? I am using Arch Linux, grep 2.20, bash 4.3.18

Answer (score 6):

The best strategy would be to use a proper html parser that can spit out the value of all `<a>` tags.

Here, `xmlstarlet` is specifically an XML parser, and your HTML may not be well-formed XML, but you might get the idea:

```
echo '<html>
<a href="000000.jpg" title="image name.jpg" target="_blank">Image name.jpg</a>
</html>' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //a
```

```
Image name.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is

```
target="_blank">([[:graph:]]*)\.(jpg|png|gif|webm)
```

This matches the literal text `target="_blank">`, followed by any number of non-whitespace characters, with one of the four strings `.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif` or `.webm` at the end. For example, the grep command would output the bold parts of the following lines:

```
<a … target="_blank">something.jpg</a>
<a … target="_blank">a.gifted.child.txt</a>
<a … target="_blank">something else.jpg</a>
<a … target="_blank">something.jpg</a>+more.jpg
```

And if you use `[[:print:]]` instead of `[[:graph:]]`, then it would match something like

```
<a … target="_blank">something.jpg</a> wibble wobble <a … target="_blank">something else.jpg</a>
```

Everything between the first matching `target …` bit and the last matching extension on the line is a match.

What you need is to exclude HTML markup characters from the match.

```
target="_blank">[^<>]*\.(jpg|png|gif|webm)</a>
```

With GNU grep, you can use the `-P` option to get constructs from [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), and in particular [zero-width assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions) that let you specify that something is preceded or followed by some constant text without including that text in the matched portion.

```
grep -o -P '(?<target="_blank">)[^<>]*\.(jpg|png|gif|webm)(?=</a>)'
```

This can still fail if there is unexpected whitespace (like a newline between the `<a>` tag and the closing `</a>`, or ). You would [do better to use a proper HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

For example, in Python with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (untested):

```
import re, sys, BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin)
for hit in soup.find_all('a', target='_blank'):
    if re.match(r'.*\.(jpg|png|gif|webm)\Z', hit.string):
        print(hit.string)
```

Similar code can be written with [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) in Perl, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) in Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
w3m -dump -T text/html "$thread" | grep -i -E -o 'File\:+([[:print:]]*)\.(jpg|png|webm|gif)'
```

w3m cleans the code and then I can grep for the file names.  (I need the literal "File:" part to distinguish a linked file from its title).  I do need [[:print:]] because it catches most whitespace, unicode chars and other printables.

which works as I intended (though I still have to figure out how to prevent overwriting files with same name but that's another day's battle)